# How to round a number to n decimal places?

Tags: python, tkinter, decimal-point

I want, what I enter in the entry field should be automatic rounded to n decimal points.

```
import Tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()

class InterfaceApp():
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent = parent
        root.title("P")
        self.initialize()


    def initialize(self):
        frPic = Tk.Frame(bg='', colormap='new')
        frPic.grid(row=0)
        a= Tk.DoubleVar()
        self.entry = Tk.Entry(frPic, textvariable=a)
        a.set(round(self.entry.get(), 2))

        self.entry.grid(row=0)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = InterfaceApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Isn't your `a` an `IntVar`, e.g. integers...?

Comment: How does that work?  When does the rounding happen?  As you type?  When focus leaves?  etc.

Comment: it's `DoubleVar()`, i have fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not get the expected result because when you run `a.set(round(self.entry, 2))` inside `initialize()` , the value of `self.entry.get()` is always `0` (the default value after creation)

You rather need to attach a [callback](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm)  to a button widget on which, after pressing, the behavior you are looking for will be executed:

```
import Tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()

class InterfaceApp():

    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent = parent
        root.title("P")
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        frPic = Tk.Frame(bg='', colormap='new')
        frPic.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.a = Tk.DoubleVar()
        self.entry = Tk.Entry(frPic, textvariable=self.a)
        self.entry.insert(Tk.INSERT,0)
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
        # Add a button widget with a callback
        self.button = Tk.Button(frPic, text='Press', command=self.round_n_decimal)
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=0)
    # Callback    
    def round_n_decimal(self):      
       self.a.set(round(float(self.entry.get()), 2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = InterfaceApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: could I make that without button..also live ?

Comment: @MirzaGrbic Could you please explain what do you mean by *a live button*?

Comment: when you enter a value, that should be automatically rounded before you press a button. Thanks a lot of Billal!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you want is not to round the float value itself, you want to show a float value with a precision of n decimal points. Try this:

```
>>> n = 2
>>> '{:.{}f}'.format( 3.1415926535, n )
'3.14'
>>> n = 3
>>> '{:.{}f}'.format( 3.1415926535, n )
'3.142'
```

Note: in your code you try to round `self.entry` .i. e. you try to round an instance of type `Tk.Entry`. You should use `self.entry.get()` which supplies you with a string.

If you are not familiar with this kind of string formatting I use look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html).

Comment: No, I want the round value itself (what you enter in the entry field, it's should be rounded.). I fixed it and it's still dont't work. `a= Tk.DoubleVar()`    `self.entry = Tk.Entry(frPic, textvariable=a)`    `a.set(round(self.entry.get(), 2))`

Comment: What do you mean by "it don't work"? Please post the output/result